# How to prove : $A ∩ A^c ⊂ \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like you to clear this doubt.

I know how to prove the inverse, but to prove how these sets are contained in the empty set, I don't know how to do it.

$$A ∩ A^c ⊂ \emptyset$$

$A^c$   is the complementary of the set $A$.

I thought about

Assuming $A ∩ A^c ⊄ \emptyset$, then it means $x ∈ A$ and $x ∈ A^c$ by the definition of intersection. However, it is impossible for the element $x$ to belong to the set $A$ and to the set $A^c$ at the same time by the definition of complement. Soon $A ∩ A^c ⊂ \emptyset$ is true.

I thought about it but I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: Note that $S \subseteq \emptyset$ is equivalent to $S = \emptyset$.

Comment: @silvia Kindly use mathjax and show you attempt, add context.

Comment: Assume not; if $A \cap A^c \ne \emptyset$, this means that there is some element $x$ such that $x \in A$ and $x \in A^c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after you adding your work in the post the conclusion is correct.

Indeed, with $X$ be a universal set and $A$ be a subset of $X$  and $A^c$ be a complement set of $A$ in $X$ so $A\cap A^{c}\subset \emptyset$ (moreover as you pointed out $A\cap A^{c}\supset \emptyset$ so $A\cap A^{c}=\emptyset$) because if by contradiction we suppose $A\cap A^{c}\not\subset \emptyset$ then there exists an element $x\in A\cap A^{c}$ then by definition of $\cap$ we have $x\in A$ and $x\in A^{c}$ and by definition of complement we get $x\in A$ and $x\not\in A$, contradiction. Hence $A\cap A^c\subset \emptyset$.

Comment: So glad I did it right.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof**. Let $U$ be a set, and let $A⊆U$, that is: let $A$ be a subset of $U$. Then the set difference $U∖A$ and is called the relative complement of A in U, or the complement of A relative to U.

$U∖A=\{x∈U:x∉A\}$

Then,

$A∩A^c=(U∖A)∩A$

$=(U∩A)∖(A∩A)$

$=(U∩A)∖A$, where the intersection is [idempotent](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_is_Idempotent) hence

$A∩A^c=∅ $

■